# Connecting to Neo4j database after importing CSV

Tags: python, csv, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I have imported my csv files using the neo4j-admin according to the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/) using the following command

```
/bin/neo4j-admin import --mode=csv --nodes all_nodes_ne_header.csv,all_nodes_ne.csv --relationships all_relations_ne_header.csv,all_relations_ne.csv
```

the result looks like

```
IMPORT DONE in 15s 997ms.
Imported:
  19354 nodes
  11759454 relationships
  58062 properties
Peak memory usage: 1.03 GB
```

and I can see a file called `graph.db` in the `data/databases` folder.

I go to python and do:

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship, Database
%matplotlib inline
%load_ext cypher

default_db = Database(db = Database())
graph = Graph("bolt://localhost:3637")
```

and after running my query I get the following:

```
Format: (http|https)://username:password@hostname:port/db/name
...
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=7474): Max retries exceeded with url: /db/data/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x12e269790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

I guess I am not doing the connection correctly within Python and didn't find anywhere in the documentation how to do it. Basically, I have not set any password, username and even don't the port. I generated a report using `neo4j-admin report` and there was not anything relevant either. therefore, I appreciate your comments on how I can build the connection and start querying from python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has to to the config file and edit the following line in the `neo4j.config`

```
# The name of the database to mount
dbms.active_database=graph.db
```

then can run `./bin/neo4j consol`

the output should end like

```
Starting Neo4j.
2019-12-01 23:42:14.731+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.5.3 ========
2019-12-01 23:42:14.743+0000 INFO  Starting...
2019-12-01 23:42:16.599+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 127.0.0.1:7687.
2019-12-01 23:42:18.122+0000 INFO  Started.
2019-12-01 23:42:19.065+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
```

then going back to the jupyter notebook ...